# How to allow three optional parameters in the URL by .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `http://example.com` and a PHP routing class that checks if some URL exists. 
I want to make a new route, which is:

`http://example.com/foo/bar/123`

but as long as I open it, the Apache redirects me to an error page. So I'm using a .htaccess. The code is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /index.php [L]
```

and it works, as long as I use `http://example.com/foo`, but once I add some other parameters, it redirects me to an error.

I'm guessing that the rewrite code is wrong. Is it wrong? 
If yes, could you suggest me the good one? 
If no, where the problem could be located?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the URI with php:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

php:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    $params = explode("/", ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/"));
    print_r($params);
}
```

`example.com/just/these/params`

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => just
    [1] => these
    [2] => params
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.php [L]
```

Try it like this. In you .htaccess every request that isn't a file on disk is redirected to index.php, I am guessing that index.php is redirecting further. I don't think you can get this route /foo/bar/123 or /foo/bar with just one line of code. Every page needs it own rewrite rule. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Actually I'd like to process every URL, or at least example.com/just/these/params, by index.php, which loads all my stuff and checks if that route exists. Say: if ($url) good; else bad;

Comment: You can capture any path with just `(.*)` or `^`. The problem is most likely in `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could help. "/index.php" will delegate to the wrong path.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache 2.2.16:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: please provide some kind of explanation too to support your answer.