# .htaccess category subcategory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

first time posting here!

I saw a lot of topics regarding .htaccess issues, but none of them seemed to work for my needs... let me explain

I'm developing a website where my client sells several types of playground toys.
The site is organized in categories. Bellow, a link to a category:

http://docs.wdesign.com.br/orimad-novo/produtos/playgrounds
this page is in fact a categories.php?alias=playgrounds

the following URL is for a product inside the "playgrounds" category

http://docs.wdesign.com.br/orimad-novo/produtos/playgrounds/brink-lar-super
this page is in fact a produtos-detalhe.php?alias=playgrounds&produto=brink-lar-super

I made the above URL using htaccess, but my client wants me to get rid of the word "produtos" in both URL, but I can't seem to get it working on my htaccess file... i'm not all familiar with it after all... my htaccess is below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^empresa/?$ empresa.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^orcamento/?$ orcamento.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^orcamento/send/?$ contato-send.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produtos/?$ produtos.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)/(.*)$ produtos-detalhe.php?alias=$1&produto=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.+)$ categorias.php?alias=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contato/?$ contato.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contato/send?$ contato-send.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^localizacao/?$ localizacao.php [NC,L]
```

Feel free to navigate the site... hope you guys can help me =)
Thank in advance!!!!

Comment: This sounds a bit strange... Your question is extremely vague. You do not explain what you actually want to do, but just give the weak hint that you "want to remove the term `produtos` without stating how things are meant to work. Your client tells you... I develop a website... But apparently you do not know the tools you are using and how they work. Don't get this wrong, but - why do you sell a solution you yourself do not know how to handle?

Comment: @arkascha sorry, i'm really not a professional developer and also i'm not familiar with htaccess, thought coming here would help me learn a bit more, hehe. My client would like the final URL for the categories, for instance, to be like this http://docs.wdesign.com.br/orimad-novo/playground, without the word "produtos". And that's what I don't know how to do in my htaccess file. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Well, why can't you simply leave that word away then? Remove it from the links you send out and remove it from the pattern in your rewriting rules so that thinks match again.

Comment: @arkascha when I remove it from the pattern in my rewriting rules it doesn't work, and it messes with the other patterns too =\ that's what i don't know how to solve =)

Comment: found a working solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542913/how-to-allow-three-optional-parameters-in-the-url-by-htaccess?rq=1

Comment: OK, so I assume you implemented some minimal rewriting on the apache level only and do the rest inside php? So like one would do using an nginx http server? Great that you found a solution! Maybe you could post your result as an answer here so that the issue gets clear and others can benefit from it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution that worked for me in this link: [How to allow three optional parameters in the URL by .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542913/how-to-allow-three-optional-parameters-in-the-url-by-htaccess?rq=1)

I erased the contents of my .htaccess files and used the example provided bt @tttony, as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Then using his php code suggestion, I did some work on index.php file.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){

    $params = explode("/", ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/"));
    @$termo1 = $params[1];
    @$termo2 = $params[2];
    $array_exists = array('empresa','produtos','orcamento','contato','localizacao');
    if(!isset($termo1) || $termo1 == "" && !isset($termo2)) {
        include "home.php";
    } elseif(in_array($termo1,$array_exists)){
        include $termo1 . ".php";
    } else {
        if(isset($termo1) && !isset($termo2)){
            include "categorias.php";
        }
        if(isset($termo1) && isset($termo2) && $termo2 == ""){
            include "categorias.php";
        }
        if(isset($termo1) && isset($termo2) && !$termo2 == ""){
            include "produtos-detalhe.php";
        }
    }    
}
```

Also did some rewriting to the files categorias.php and produtos-detalhe.php, as they were getting values from $_GET variables, and now they are getting those same values from $termo1 and $termo2.

That's it... may not be that polished, but it's working.
Maybe one day, soon, I'll learn a better solution.
That's life, we're always learning =)

link for visualization: http://docs.wdesign.com.br/orimad-novo