# .htaccess - remove index.php, redirect with multiple parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm searching but I can't do work it.

I have the following .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite request URL
#   Input:  index/VIDEO/
#   Output: index.php?id=VIDEO
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```

It work fine changing the following url:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/index.php?id=234556
```

To

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/234556
```

But I've add a second parameter (license), so I need rewrite the following URL:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/index.php?id=234556&license=23432532
```

To

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/234556/23432532
```

Or

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/234556&license=23432532
```

I've been trying multiple ways searching here but I cant do that this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*?)$    /index.php?id=$1&license=$2    [L,QSA]
```

In which, first parameter holds all values until it finds `/`. Next parameter holds all. You can repeat first expression multiple times as well.

---

**Alternate method:**

But when your application needs some more search parameters that needs to be dynamically handled, you can make use of `REQUEST_URI` in PHP.

In that case, your `RewriteRule` can be like:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And in PHP, you can retrieve all the values using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    $params = explode("/", ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/"));
    print_r($params);
}
```

See another [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7380631/5447994). In that way, other pages can utilize the same rewrite rule for different purpose.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Im get "Object no location in Xampp". Im use RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*?)$    /index.php?id=$1&license=$2    [L,QSA]
Url to test:
http://localhost/api/source/videos/28652187/23432324

Comment: remove `/` before `index.php`. Try this way: `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*?)$ index.php?id=$1&license=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: BTW, I can't test your `localhost` URL :)